# nameValuePair key added in new JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

When I am building a json object from string it is appended with a root key "nameValuePairs".

```
String curStr = "{\"e\": \"{}\", \"f\": \"{}\", \"g\": \"{}\"}";
JSONObject oldObj = new JSONObject(curStr);
```

results to

```
{"nameValuePairs":{"b":"{}","c":"{}","a":"{}"}}
```

Why?

Any way to prevent that?

Btw, I am using the string json to represent the actual json which I will use later.

Comment: Your JSON is syntatically correct, but I guess you want objects inside your variables: `{"nameValuePairs":{"b":{},"c":{},"a":{}}}` (remove the quotes)

Comment: I've tried your code and I don't haven any "nameValuePairs". How did you print the json result?

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
   String jsonStr = gson.toJson(jsonObj);
   System.out.println(jsonStr);

Comment: Ok, figured it out.

Gson is causing it...using json.toString() instead doesn't add the key.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @Enrichman, somehow you answered my question or lead me to it. thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If you want I can write an answer and you can accept it. Otherwise you can simply close the question. :)

Comment: I've written a more complete answer, if you need any help just ask. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your json is syntactically correct but I guess you wished to represent objects as values, in your case the curly brackets are evaluated as simple strings:

```
String curStr = "{\"e\": \"{}\", \"f\": \"{}\", \"g\": \"{}\"}";
JSONObject oldObj = new JSONObject(curStr);
```

using a json like this instead will produce values as objects:

```
String curStr = "{\"e\": {}, \"f\": {}, \"g\": {}}";
JSONObject oldObj = new JSONObject(curStr);
```

Anyway, I've tried to create that JSONObject and then print a toString of it, and it will simply print the json, without any accessory name.

As you find out in the comment the problem was given by Gson, that will evaluate the JSONObject as a map. I've tried a little example and I've got "map" as field. Probably I've tried a different version of Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(oldObj);
```

result: `{"map":{"f":"{}","g":"{}","e":"{}"}}`

If you want to create a custom object and deserialize a json with Gson create a class with those properties and use the fromJson(String json, Class clazz) method

```
public class Test {
    private String e;
    private String f;
    private String g;
}
```

and

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Test myTestObj = gson.fromJson(curStr, Test.class);
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try jsonStringer instead.

Something like below code:

```
 JSONStringer jObject = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
               .key("UserName").value(userNameValue)
               .key("Name").value(nameValue)
               .key("EmailId").value(emailIdValue)
               .key("CountryId").value(contryIdValue)
               .key("CountryName").value("") // It should be blank As Spanish Name is not set if User have App in Spanish
               .key("State").value(stateValue)
               .key("City").value(cityValue)
               .key("ImageByteArray").value(imageBytes)
             .endObject();
```

**UPDATE**

I have just use your code in my App and check it.

Its showing me the result as we have formed.
Result i am getting is:

```
{
   "f": "{}",
   "g": "{}",
   "e": "{}"
}
```

Please check your packages you are importing.
For your reference i am importing below class to represent json object.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Just import above class and see the result.

Let me know if you still have any query.

Comment: there are some disadvantages in using JSONStringer instead of .toString(), read it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html

Comment: I need to completely remove the nameValuePairs key... is it possible in my raw JSON?